# What does 1 << 32 mean in Go?

Tags: go, bit-shift

What does `1 << 32` mean in Go? If I understand correctly it means `2^32`. Or am I mistaken? And if my opinion above is right, what does this code do?

```
min := int(^uint(0) >> 1)
```

Comment: that's a standard shift operator (http://golang.org/ref/spec#Operators). This isn't specific to go.

Comment: What is "shift"? Can You explain more, pls.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation

Comment: JimB, thanks, probably I understand what is "shift". It's "bit line", ex 1<<8 is `1111 1111` (or equal is `2^8`) and `<<` works as "upstream", from low to hi, and `>>` work from hi to low. I try understanding on [Go Play](http://play.golang.org/p/SLfvHQn_6Q)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 is shifted 32 times.

Shift is a bitwise operation. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_shift